# Is it OK in hsqldb to invoke the CHECKPOINT sql while another sql might be in progress?

Tags: hsqldb

In other words, must I synchronize CHECKPOINT with another queries or can I simply execute it periodically in a dedicated thread?

My DB does not write the log. I am OK if the data is lost upon crash, but I do want to flush it periodically and make sure it is flushed when the application is terminated.

**EDIT**

The following items describe my scenario:

1. Run a bunch of short unit tests inserting items in dedicated DBs using an embedded hsqldb engine.
2. Run hsqldb as a standalone server connecting to one of the DBs created during the unit tests.
3. Open [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) trying to connect to the running standalone hsqldb server.

The SQL Workbench/J shows no tables at all. But if I add CHECKPOINT after having inserted all the records, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB always performs the checkpoint safely. It uses a separate thread that waits until all connections have committed then locks the database and performs the checkpoint.

CHECKPOINT is useful for reducing the amount of time it takes to restart a database after a crash. This does not apply to your database which has disabled the log.

If you are not writing a log, checkpoints may be unnecessary. The use of checkpoint in this scenario is to reclaim the spaces for deleted lobs (in version 2.3.0). It also writes out all the data.

If you want to flush the database at the end of your tests, you can execute SHUTDOWN instead.

Comment: Please, see my EDIT. Does it mean the DB was not flushed upon the unit test termination? Is it a peculiarity of the unit test environment?

Comment: OK. I missed the point about flushing the app. Will update the answer.

Comment: I am more worried about the production code. If I never do CHECKPOINT, then the data is written out every 10,000K or 50,000 rows by default, right? Which says nothing about the time, this could take however long it takes to fill the cache. Am I right?

Comment: Don't worry about data being written out, the engine writes the data only when it needs the space in the cache. If you want the database to be usable after loading data, just do a SHUTDOWN and no checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The data loading process may take days with the data flowing in every few seconds. Suppose the server is restarted before the cache is written out for the first time. Then the DB on disk is empty, I would not even see the tables (this is what happened in the unit tests). So, you suggest just shutting down the DB at this point.

Comment: Yes. The server should not be started while the database is open. Start it only after shutdown.