# tomee server output - what those it mean?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, output, apache-tomee

What thas it mean in Tomee Server Output ?

```
INFO: Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary". 
org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: Checkpoint start  org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent 
INFO: checkpointClose start  org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: checkpointClose end  org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: Checkpoint end
```

Comment: Are you using an HSQL DB engine?

Comment: no i don't use it - certainly not consciously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember after playing a bit with tomee is that you should have a default HSQL test DB hardcoded in the tomee.xml config file. So, if you don't use it, feel free to remove from that file and restart tomee.

The log you posted are checks from the HSQL driver. If you want to go deeper, please take a look at this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933626/is-it-ok-in-hsqldb-to-invoke-the-checkpoint-sql-while-another-sql-might-be-in-pr)